# First elements click functions didn't worked in Owl Carousal

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, owl-carousel

I have a carousel that is integrated and generated through the Owl carousel. These image divs contain two buttons which were animated through CSS animations. Buttons are actually `<a>` tags.
When the page is rendered these `<a>` tags click function does not works in the first element(div). i have tried with the `event.preventDefault()` method also but nothing works. following is my code

**HTML**

```
<a href  onClick={(e) => viewMovie(e,movieBannertop)}
style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
Now Showing
</a>
```

**Function**

```
  const viewMovie = (e,movieData) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (movieData.bookingOpen) {
      localStorage.setItem("movieName", movieData.name);
      localStorage.setItem("movieId", movieData.id);
      navigate(`/movieBooking?movieid=${movieData.id}&name=${movieData.name}`);
    } else {
      setOpen(true);
    }
  };
```

**CSS**

```
display:inline-block;
width:150px;
height:50px;
text-align:center;
line-height:50px;
border:1px solid #ff4444;
margin-right:-900px;
background:transparent;
color:#ffffff;
margin-top:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
transition: all 0.5s;
```